# How to split comma delimited values into multiple rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python and SQLite to manipulate a database.

I have an SQLite Table `Movies` that looks like this:

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA, Germany, Mexico 
| 2              | Brazil, Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

I would like to split the comma delimited values in `Country` and insert them into another table `Countries` so that `Countries` table looks like this

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA
| 1              | Germany
| 1              | Mexico
| 2              | Brazil
| 2              | Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

How do I do split the values from `Country` column in `Movies` table and insert them into `Country` column in `Countries` table?

I can't do this in pure SQLite **how can I combine Python**?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have multiple identical entries in the ID column?

Comment: Yes, because I need to be able to retrieve movie ID where Country = USA for example